# How to replace full stop space and lowercase character with comma space lowercase character?

Tags: notepad++

I have some OCRed documents where the commas have been recognized as full stops in some places.

Like this:

```
staring thoughtfully into his empty coffee cup. and he absently
```

How do I find these instances in the document and replace them without having to find every '. ' manually?

I can't get my head around the different expressions.

I do know I can use `[a-z]\.(.)[A-Z]` to find and mark 'p. a' in this example but it also marks 'p. A'.

I only want to change the 'p. a' in these instances to 'p, a'.

Is this possible?

Comment: This isn't something you can do with a regex, what about _"Thinking quickly. Jon came up with an example!"_ - how does a pattern know if that should be a comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(.)` part captures any char except a newline in a group, and `[A-Z]` matches an uppercase char.

In this case you don't need the group, and you can match a lowercase char a-z followed by a dot and assert spaces to the right followed by a lowercase char again.

To not remove the already matched lowercase char, you can use `\K` to clear what is matched so far. In the the replacement use a comma.

-> Enable "Regular expression"

-> Check "Match case"

-> Check "Wrap around"

**Find what:**

```
[a-z]\K\.(?=\h+[a-z])
```

**Replace with:**

```
,
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EMPduC/1)

Comment: This is great to find the places where 'word. word' are but I am unable to execute the replace. Find: [a-z]\K\.(?=\h+[a-z]) Replace: [a-z]\K\,(?=\h+[a-z]) doesn't work and neither does Find: [a-z]\K\.(?=\h+[a-z]) Replace: ,. Sorry. What should be written in the replace with field? And how do I break lines in this comment section?

Comment: @ErikLiterature Did you enable regular expressions, and then replaced all? You can replace with just a comma. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I did. If I press replace all it replaces all '. ' with ', ' but also before capital characters.<BR>'two weeks before. It had made him' becomes 'two weeks before, It had made him'.

Comment: @ErikLiterature You have to check "Match case" as well.

Comment: Okay. I thought I had done that in the main document but hadn't. I think it works now.  Thank you.  I can't seem to get line breaks right. Two spaces doesn't work.